# Disable edit and destroy user in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to use only `:new` and `:create` actions from Devise's `:registrable` module. What is better way to do that? Remove `:registrable` and create my own controller for sign up?

Comment: Note sure if this works with devise, but try in `routes.rb`: `devise_for :users, :only => [:new, :create]`.